# excel macro not copying cells correctly

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I have adapted a VBA macro I found online in order to copy lots (50+) xls files into one big excel worksheet in a new file. They all have the same columns.

Works just fine, but I noticed that some of the excel files have a crucial value inserted as string instead of number.

Copying that string results in a "wrong" number: if origin is 3099,213 my result is 3.099.213 (european notation with comma for decimals and dot for thousands), so x1000 in size.

My question: how can I copy so that the format is maintained? I can then later easily convert the string into number in the outputfile without problem.

```
Sub MergeSelectedWorkbooks()
    Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim SelectedFiles() As Variant
    Dim NRow As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim NFile As Long
    Dim WorkBk As Workbook
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim DestRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    ' Create a new workbook and set a variable to the first sheet.
    Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

    ' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
    FolderPath = "G:\gas 2016-2017\distribution\CLASS\0351\"

    ' Set the current directory to the the folder path.
    ChDrive FolderPath
    ChDir FolderPath

    ' Open the file dialog box and filter on Excel files, allowing multiple files
    ' to be selected.
    SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)

    ' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
    NRow = 1

    ' Loop through the list of returned file names
    For NFile = LBound(SelectedFiles) To UBound(SelectedFiles)
        ' Set FileName to be the current workbook file name to open.
        FileName = SelectedFiles(NFile)

        ' Open the current workbook.
        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FileName)

        ' Set the cell in column A to be the file name.
        SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow).Value = FileName

        LastRow = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                 After:=WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Cells.Range("A1"), _
                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                 LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
        Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A8:Z" & LastRow)

        ' Set the destination range to start at column B and be the same size as the source range.
        Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow)
        Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
           SourceRange.Columns.Count)

        ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.
        DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

        ' Increase NRow so that we know where to copy data next.
        NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

        ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
        WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False
    Next NFile

    ' Call AutoFit on the destination sheet so that all data is readable.
    SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value2`

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't change the output. Strange thing is, strings that begin with 0, like 0,938729, are copied correctly.

Comment: Are these numbers being stored as strings or values?

Comment: I have checked a couple of files, and the ones where the origin is "string" are converted correctly with format "general"; whereas the ones where the origin is general, but the cell has the little green triangle telling me it's a string, get converted wrongly, with format number. Very confusing. I receive these files every month from 50+ companies, and unfortunately I cannot ask them to conform to one standard.

Comment: It works now, I changed into a copy-paste with xlPasteSpecial, BUT it asks all the time what to do with the enormous amount of data on the clipboard, so I can't just sit there and wait for it to finish by itself.

Comment: Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:Z" & LastRow)
        ' new code
        SourceRange.Copy
       
        Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("B" & NRow)
        Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
           SourceRange.Columns.Count)
        DestRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

Comment: Try adding `Application.CutCopyMode = False` after you have pasted the data

Comment: That works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use IsNumber on the 2nd row of the current column to see if it is a number, then when you bring in the value into the new sheet, set as val(SourceRange.Value)?